# SQL server 2005 SP4 differential backup is failing

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

We have an SQL server 2005 with SP4, x86. When we attempt to take the differential backup, we are getting the following error message.

> Cannot perform a differential backup for database "ABCD", because a
>   current database backup does not exist. Perform a full database backup
>   by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3035) BACKUP DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

A differential backup is a "changes only" backup, and therefore can only be done when there is a previous full backup to work from. If you create a new database (or attach one from another server), and don't take a full backup, there no "original backup" to get changes since.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a differential backup until a full backup of the database has been taken.  The backup/restore order is full/differential[/differential].